# AWS - Can't access backup file in S3 bucket

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssms, amazon-rds

I've been setuping a database on AWS for a project. I already have the database built on my local computer so I want to transfer it rather than starting over.

I created the online database using the free template in RDS, made it publicly accessible. I also created an option group with SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option. I then went in the Database to add the IAM role of the option group with feature S3_INTEGRATION.

Once that was done, I created a bucket that I made as public as possible (Block public access (bucket settings all to off) where I uploaded my .bak file which I made public via the "Make public via ACL" action.

I then went to SSMS and ran the following queries:

```
use master
go

exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
@restore_db_name='[dbname]',
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::[bucketname]/[backupfile].bak',
@with_norecovery=1,
@type='FULL';
go

use master
go
select * from msdb.dbo.rds_fn_task_status(null,0) 
go
```

Of course, [dbname], [bucketname] and [backupfile] were replaced with the actual informations. However, after 1-2minutes, rds_fn_task_status(null,0) returns an error saying

> [2021-11-29 01:44:22.393] Aborted the task because of a task failure
> or a concurrent RESTORE_DB_NORECOVERY request. [2021-11-29
> 01:44:22.770] Task has been aborted [2021-11-29 01:44:22.770] Access
> Denied

What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

Local Database type:          SQL

RDS Engine:                   SQL Server Express Edition

RDS Db Status:                Available

RDS Db Publicly accessible:   Yes

Db and Bucket in same region: Yes

Account used in SSMS:         Master account same as when creating the database

Encryption Enabled:           Not in DB nor Bucket

I'm new to AWS so I'm probably missing something (it's quite confusing to use). But every tutorial to restore a db backup that I've found mentions that these are all the required steps and I should have access.

Comment: When creating the option group did you select Enable Encryption?  That would then assume you have access to the KMS key (specified with an additional parameter) during msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database.

Comment: No, encryption isn't on on the bucket, I see a 'Key' in the object overview which I tried putting in the @kms_master_key_arn parameter, but it didn't work either. I don't see anything about encryption in my option group. Encryption is also off on the database